# Parsing a HTTP request

Tags: java

For a long time I stuck in parsing some information in HTTP.

The thing I dont understand: Some lines could be parsed, other lines couldn't!

```
public String parse(String arg) throws IOException {
    scanner = new Scanner(req);
    StringBuilder buildValue = new StringBuilder();
    boolean lineFound = false;
    int sf;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        thisLine = new StringReader(scanner.nextLine());
        searchFor = new StringReader(arg);
        lineFound = false;
        for (int tl; (tl = thisLine.read()) != -1;) {
            sf = searchFor.read();
            if (sf != -1) {
                if (sf == tl && !lineFound) {
                    builder.append((char)tl);
                }
            } else {
                if (lineFound) {
                    buildValue.append((char)tl);
                }
                if (!lineFound && builder.toString().equals(arg)) {
                    builder.delete(0, builder.capacity());
                    System.out.println("GEFUNDEN");
                    lineFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    thisLine.close();
    searchFor.close();
    builder.delete(0, builder.capacity());
    String parsed = buildValue.toString();
    buildValue.delete(0, buildValue.capacity());
    return parsed;
}
```

---

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

Connection: keep-alive

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4*
```

---

The only lines that  could be parsed:
   - Host:
   - Accept:

I don't understand that anymore, so I wanted to ask here.

Best regards,
Ercksen

EDIT:

I forgot the fields:

```
private String req;
private Scanner scanner;
private StringReader reader;
private StringReader searchFor;
private StringReader thisLine;
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: Why would you parse it yourself in the first place? That aside, don't just dump code-explain precisely what isn't working, what you've tried to solve it, what the specific failures are, etc.

Comment: What? Everything works fine by me, just with the problem that some lines return null - what I can't explain to me, becouse every StringBuilder and StringReader is re-initialized/deleted!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [HttpComponents library from Apache.](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Comment: Ok, I will try it out!

Comment: By the way, do you see the problem? I first wanna try it my own way! (without external librarys) ...